# How to measure performance impact of GCC linking option -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now on binary startup on ARM

Tags: performance, gcc, binary, startup, elf

I'm trying to find a way to measure the start-up performance impact of using relro and early binding linkage options on an ARM platform.

Someone can suggest me how to find the time spent linking shared libraries for a binary compiled with that options ?

Many thanks.

---

Edit 1: 
No time information on my machine.

> root@arm:/# LD_DEBUG=statistics /bin/date
>
> ```
>   1470:                      number of relocations: 90
>   1470:           number of relocations from cache: 3
>   1470:             number of relative relocations: 1207 Thu Jan  1 00:17:00 UTC 1970
>   1470:     
>   1470:     runtime linker statistics:
>   1470:                final number of relocations: 108
>   1470:     final number of relocations from cache: 3
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GLIBC:

```
$ LD_DEBUG=statistics /bin/date
      4494:
      4494:     runtime linker statistics:
      4494:       total startup time in dynamic loader: 932928 clock cycles
      4494:                 time needed for relocation: 299052 clock cycles (32.0%)
      4494:                      number of relocations: 106
      4494:           number of relocations from cache: 4
      4494:             number of relative relocations: 1276
      4494:                time needed to load objects: 420660 clock cycles (45.0%)
Fri Feb 28 16:40:48 PST 2014
```

Build your binary with and without `-z,relro` and compare the numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately on ARM architecture the output is different and don't give any measure of time.

Comment: @boos The ARM vs. x86 is unlikely to have anything to do with this. You are probably using C runtime library (`libc`) that is not `GLIBC`. Reading sources for that library and/or enhancing it to produce the info you need is likely to help. At a minimum, update your question stating *which* runtime library you are actually using.